# Update ember component on model change

Tags: ember.js

Using Ember 1.13

I have two nested resources, one of which renders a component based off the model returned by a dynamic route

something like

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('maps', function () {
    this.resource('map', { path: '/:map_id' });
  });
});
```

and a template for a map which renders a component

```
map.hbs

{{some-component model=model}}
{{#each maps as |map|}}
  {{#link to 'map' map}}{{map.name}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

when I first hit

```
/maps/1
```

the component renders

when I hit one of the links and go to

```
/maps/2
```

it appears as if the route never gets hit and the component never updates

is this a result of using link-to or is it true the route is not getting hit because just changing the model inside of a route does cause the same lifecyle hooks to go off?

What is the best way to force this component to rerender?

Comment: Part of the answer is that you are passing in a map model, so your model hook in your map route will not be executed again. For the rest, I would need more of your code, especially your map route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably doing something wrong.

Here's a basic working example:

```
<h3>maps.index</h3>

<ul>
{{#each model as |item|}}
  <li>
    {{link-to item.name 'maps.map' item}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

```
<h3>maps.map</h3>

{{link-to "Back to index" 'maps.index'}}

<hr>

{{x-map map=model}}
```

```
<h4>components/x-map</h4>

<p>Id:   {{map.id}}</p>
<p>name: {{map.name}}</p>
```

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('maps', function () {
    this.route('map', { path: '/:map_id' });
  });
});

App.MapsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.findAll('map');
  }
});

App.MapsMapRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('map', params.mapId);
  }
});

App.Map = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/voquba/4/edit?html,js,output

Note that instead of passing the whole record into the child route:

```
{{link-to item.name 'maps.map' item}}
```

You can pass only its ID:

```
{{link-to item.name 'maps.map' item.id}}
```

This is useful when you know the ID but don't have the whole record at hand. Ember Data will look up the record of given ID in the store. If it's not there, it'll fetch it via the route's model hook.

Comment: Amazing answer! You are correct in that you made me realize that the issue was not that the component properties were not updating.

Comment: ha I'm in the middle of finishing that comment! I may have a quick follow up but you will surely recieve your choose and upvote either way

Comment: The component was rendering a google map  and the component was calling render  .on(''didInsertElement") which was not being called again when changing the model.